# Mark specific date in pgfgantt

Tags: pgfgantt

I have looked into pgfgantt and I want to mark specific days. For instance how can I make the date box 01 with background red and also the dotted box below with the same color? I can not see how I can customize the vertical dates. I might want to customize more specific dates so I can't use the style list since it is assuming a regular pattern.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    time slot format=isodate,
    hgrid,
    vgrid,
  ]{2018-04-16}{2018-05-16}
  \gantttitlecalendar{month=name, day}\\  
  \ganttbar{}{2018-04-22}{2018-04-26}
  \ganttbar{}{2018-04-30}{2018-05-02}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]